# How to fill adobe reader protected forms in pdf?

Tags: php, pdf-generation

There are some immigration pdf forms that are protected to open just on adobe reader and have some other restriction like importing data inside adobe.
I saw some softwares that found a way to automatic fill-in this forms.
Does anyone know a library or API that can help me to do that.
My software is made with php/laravel.
This is one of the company doing it:
https://support.caseeasy.ca/en/articles/5986426-add-forms-to-a-case-record-send-the-auto-complete-request
This is one of forms:
https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm1294e.pdf
Thank you!

Tried some php library to fill forms, but they can't even open the file.

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to keep the same format, just automatically fill the form using some language like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one product family that can handle those forms in any sensible way since they are NOT PDF (They are dynamic thus NOT adhering to ISO OPEN PDF Standards). Here you can see what a mess they make in PDF apps and viewers that are not Adobe Licensed, that includes ALL Adobe CLONE READERS and most applications, some are more graceful at failing than others. Different readers will see different numbers of pages , since the contents are written by Adobe Live products. Here it is 3 pages in another case it may be 5 and other cases I have seen 30. However there is only the ONE PDF page and that is the cover.

[image]

A Good Reader like Acrobat DC will fail to handle them by showing a cover to say you must buy Adobe products from Reader 8 or above and disable security.

[image]

### The REASON

There are no libraries, **other than Adobe ones** as the pages are "**changelings**" they do not stand still for fixed entry they are called **dynamic** because **the fields will morph** during entry so here the file starts as 4 pages. and on completion by a SOLE person it will be 6 pages so fields that were on page 4 may or may not appear on page 6. Likewise the form allows for 99 persons, so if every bodies details are entered the number of fields and their identity shifts in description and location.

[image]

Comment: Sorry. That is not what I need. I don’t need a reader. I need a library that can automatically fill the fields out like pdf.js. Tks anyway.